# Does GetHashCode() work correctly in MonoTouch for NSObject-derived objects?

Tags: xamarin.ios, gethashcode

I'm trying to figure out if MonoTouch correctly calls the underlying "hash" message when you call GetHashCode() from a NSObject drived object.  A quick check of the implementation of GetHashCode() (in MD's assembly browser) for an arbitrary object (NSAttributedString in my example) has it calling object.InternalGetHashCode(), so I suspect it doesn't call "hash".  "hash" doesn't appear to be exposed either, which makes me suspect there's another way to get to it.  Anyone been down this road before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good observation, this is a bug.

I will fix this in MonoMac, and for our upcoming iPhone/.NET product

Answer (score 0):

```
object.InternalGetHashCode()
```

... is returned in Assembly Browser for System.Object as well, regardless if it is a MonoTouch or Mono project.

Yes, it works correctly.

Comment: The default implementation of gethashcode creates a hash of the members in the object.  In this case, wouldn't mono only be looking at the pointer to the objective c object, not the underlying contents?  To be useful, calling gethashcode for two nsstrings that have the same content should return the same value.  Unless there is a call to [Nsstring hash] happening somehow, I don't see how that could work.  (typed on my iPad, please forgive the lazy caps ;)